How to use RBAC with a scope limitation
I want to use RBAC in auth0, quite new to this and need some help in understanding this conceptually. The requirement is RBAC but there are multiple departments and the person can have a different role in each department so the token would need to be scoped to reflect this. Also need some help in understanding how the token would look.
Here is an Example of the role they can have in 2 departments:
Person 1
Role admin
Department: HR Department
Role viewer
Department: IT Department
Does this structure still make sense for RBAC?
